# Why does my Login only work in these specific circumstances?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-7, laravel-ui

I am using **laravel/ui** with Laravel 7.15.0 and PHP7.3 to build a login for my website, but I have issues logging in my user.

I have the checkmark option for the remember_token on my login page.

## What is happening on my login page

#### First case: 'remember_token' column *exists* in my users table

When I click on the login button, it will shortly authenticate the user. If I dump 'Auth::check()' in the method 'authenticated' in my LoginController (made by laravel/ui), it will return true. But then the user won't be logged in anymore, once it redirects me to my home page.

When 'remember me' is ticked, it will write a value to the column in my users table .

#### Second case: 'remember_token' column *does not exist* in my users table AND the 'remember me' box is ticked

Now this is the weird part. When I don't have that column, on login, it will throw an error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'remember_token' in 'field list'
```

BUT then when I navigate to any page and run Auth::check() there, it returns true, so the user has been logged in.

If the box has not been ticked it has the same result as the first case.

## What I have tried

So far I have tried to look into how the remember_token thing works in the laravel/ui code. Using the token should not even be necessary though if I am not mistaken.

## Some infos

1. I have not changed my Authentication guard
2. I have changed my user.php and LoginController.php since my users
   table has a different name and column names.
3. I have wrapped my routes in the 'web' middleware, since apparently
   that might be necessary to persist the session.

I can provide more info about my code if necessary. Any help would be appreciated!

**This is my User.php file:**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * If timestamps should be used in the database.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * The table where the users are stored.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $table = 'backend_user';

    /**
     * The primary key of the table.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'bck_userid';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'bck_userid', 'bck_fullname', 'bck_password', 'bck_email'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'bck_password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    // protected $casts = [
    //     'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    // ];

    public function getAuthIdentifierName()
    {
        return 'bck_email';
    }

    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->bck_email;
    }

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {   
        return $this->bck_password;
    }
}
```

**And this is the definition of my "users table".** Its name is 'backend_user':
[image: Link]

Comment: Can you share the ```app/User.php``` and the ```users``` migration ?

Comment: Hi - I added it to the original post

Comment: You sure if your browser cookies are working fine ?

Comment: I think they are working fine. I tried it in multiple browsers.

Comment: could you share class that you use for authentication... seems like that where the issue is unless you have issue with sessions.

Comment: The class is provided by laravel/ui, LoginController.php. It has a trait 'AuthenticatesUsers'. So I assumed that laravel/ui would handle all that stuff.
I am also using a class customUserProvider in which I have overridden the method 'validateCredentials' (from the EloquentUserProvider) to always return true for now.